# How can I implement write through caching in Rails 3 similar to cache-money?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, cache-money

I recently inherited a Rails 2.3 application that I'm now trying to upgrade to Rails 3.  Cache-money is an integral part of the application so I want to make sure we have the same functionality in place when we go to Rails 3.  However, my research on the subject has shown that cache-money is not compatible with Rails 3 (due to the use of unsupported AR methods :find_every and :find_from_ids).

I've seen a couple of comments and blogs mention that implementing the type of write through caching with Rails 3 that cache-money provided should be a trivial task.  Any ideas on how to approach implementing write through caching with Rails 3?

Answer (score 1):

Last week I launched a new write-through-cache gem for Rails 3, see 
https://github.com/orslumen/record-cache.

The reason I built it, is because we were using cache money in a Rails 2.3 project and recently migrated to Rails 3. So chances are, it will also serve you well.

Writing your own write-though caching in Rails 3 does not sound like a trivial task to me. If you do find a trivial way, please be sure to copy me in on that.

Comment: I've forked record-cache to support Rails 4 Active Record. https://github.com/mikeatlas/record-cache